# download Great Britain boundaries as shapefile for GIS

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for a shapefile (readable e.g. in QGIS) which only contains the Great Britain boundaries. In other words, I only need the island/s boundaries.

I have already checked and downloaded the 'Boundary-Line-GB' from OS Open Data (https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) but the shapefile has been showing also the GB regions' boundaries (which I don't need).

Any suggestion on where I can download it for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it here: https://census.edina.ac.uk/easy_download.html

Just click on `InFuse Great Britain, 2011` and select the shapefile format.

Direct link for download: https://census.edina.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/infuse_gb_2011.zip

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already have seen these weblinks that may have what you are looking for.

http://www.diva-gis.org/

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/first.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Both the Strategi and Meridian [OS Open Data](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) sets contain a coastline layer.